# automatic indentation by units in align environment

Tags: amsmath, alignment

The [AMS style guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf), p.118, says "If there is a long expression before the first verb, align succeeding verbs with a two-em quad indent from the left."

[image]

Right now I can achieve this with a `&` on the first line and `&\hspace{2em}` on all succeeding lines. Is there some way to achieve it with `&`'s alone or do I have to keep writing `\hspace{2em}`?

Comment: You could replace `\hspace{2em}` with `\qquad`...

Comment: @Mico OK, thanks for the shortcut

Comment: The `2em` "rule" is useful, but it's not a fundamental law of nature. Just settle on a spacing rule you can live with.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Thanks for noticing! I've posted a corrected version of the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\MoveEqLeft` from [mathtools](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\MoveEqLeft xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
& = xxx + xxx \\
& = xx + xxxxxx.
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: equation example]

If you give it without the optional argument it is moved `[2em]`. But you can also say `\MoveEqLeft[3]` to move 3em.

Answer (score 3):

For the multirow equation at hand, you could place the `&` alignment symbol in front of `f(x)` instead of in front of `\abs[\bigg]{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\abs[\bigg]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}
  &f(x)g_N(x)\,d\mu(x)} \\
  &\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \abs{\lambda_k}\,\norm{a_k}_{L_p^q} 
       \biggl(\int_{\!S_k} \abs{{}\cdots{}}^{q'} d\mu(x)\biggr)^{\!1/q'} \\
  &\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \abs{\lambda_k} \cdots
\end{align*}

% OP's version
\begin{align*}
&\abs[\bigg]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)g_N(x)\,d\mu(x)} \\
&\qquad\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \abs{\lambda_k}\,\norm{a_k}_{L_p^q} 
       \biggl(\int_{\!S_k} \abs{{}\cdots{}}^{q'} d\mu(x)\biggr)^{\!1/q'} \\
&\qquad\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \abs{\lambda_k} \cdots
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because you know everything up to the $f(x)$ to measure 2em?

Comment: @Hasse1987 - Happy coincidence, no more.